# Modulus operator changes

Tags: c++, modulus

> $5.6/4 in C++03 states- "If both
>   operands are nonnegative then the
>   remainder is nonnegative;if not, the
>   sign of the remainder is
>   implementation-defined<sup>74)</sup>.

where Note 74 is

> According to work underway toward the
>   revision of ISO C, the preferred
>   algorithm for  integer division
>   follows the rules defined inthe ISO
>   Fortran standard, ISO/IEC 1539:1991,
>   in which the quotient is always
>   rounded toward zero.

C++0x states -

> $5.6/4- "For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;<sup>79</sup> if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result, `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to a.

Note 79 says

> This is often called truncation towards zero.

So I have two questions:

- Can someone explain this concept of 'truncation towards zero'?
- Is modulus with negative operands a defined behavior in C++0x?

Comment: Alas, the new definition still doesn't have the basic modulo property that is most often wanted: A mod B should be guaranteed to produce a value between 0 and B, including 0 but excluding B.

Comment: @swestrup: it's all about priorities. If you require A%B ∈ [0,B), and you also require (A/B)*B + A%B == A, then A/B must have a perverse rounding rule viz. truncate towards -∞. 10/-3 == -4 under such rounding, and (-A)/B != -(A/B).

Comment: @Philip Potter: In this case 'truncation' and 'rounding', do they mean the same?

Comment: chubsdad: good question! Here I'm using "rounding" to mean "any scheme for converting a real to an integer by discarding information" and I use truncation to mean "rounding by always going in a fixed direction, towards zero or -inf". Another rounding scheme is "nearest integer": where 2.3 -> 2 and 2.7 -> 3. This rounding scheme is not a truncation - nor is it commonly used in integer divide operations in programming languages. My usage is probably not standard, but I hope this clarifies my comment.

Comment: Yes, but this 'perverse' rounding scheme is the one that is the one that is needed in the vast majority of cases when working with signed integers. I've yet to see any use cases that show the current definition to be very useful. In fact, its usually justified by being hardware efficient, and that's because the hardware gets it wrong too. Perl's modulo operator gets it right, unless one uses integer mode...

Comment: @PhilipPotter: I think the relations that `(A+m)%m==A%m` and `(A+d)/d==(A+d)+1` would be more useful than `(-A)/B==-(A/B)`.  When drawing graphics using integer maths that are translated to put 0 in the middle of a window, there can be a really ugly seam at the transition between positive and negative numbers; such a seam could have been avoided if the `/` operator rounded toward negative infinity.  Note also that division or modulus of a signed number by a power of two will be faster using round-toward-negative-infinity semantics on the division.

Comment: @swestrup: If I had my druthers and a language wasn't going to mandate `-1 % m == (m-1)`, I'd loosen the rules so that that if except when either `n` and `m` are both positive, or `n` is a multiple of `m`, `n % m` could arbitrarily return the positive or negative modulus, and `n / m` could arbitrarily round up or down, with no requirement that the results being consistent even for a given combination of values.  Such a rule would allow an application to perform computations involving constant power-of-two divisors or bases without having to include signed-math cleanup code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Truncation towards zero means converting a real number to an integer by selecting the next integer nearest zero. Equivalently, you write the number down, and ignore everything after the decimal point, whether the number is positive or negative.

Consider 11/4 = 2.75 -- if you truncate this towards zero, you get 2.

consider -11/4 or 11/-4 = -2.75 -- if you truncate this towards zero, you get -2.

It's important for some maths operations that (a/b)*b + a%b == a. If we must make this equation hold, and we also accept that integer division truncates towards zero, then we can deduce the operation of the `%` operator as follows:

```
a == 11, b == 4:
a/b == 2, 2*4 + a%b == 11, therefore a%b == 3.

a == -11, b == 4:
a/b == -2, -2 * 4 + a%b == -11, therefore a%b == -3.

a == 11, b == -4:
a/b == -2, -2 * -4 + a%b == 11, therefore a%b == 3.

a == -11, b == -4:
a/b == 2, 2 * -4 + a%b == -11, therefore a%b == -3.
```

It might be confusing at first, but C++0x is defining the behaviour of the `a%b` operator using the equation `(a/b)*b + a%b == a`. This equation holds even for negative numbers, so `a%b` is defined for negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

a) Consider `(±5)/(±3) -> ±1`. On the number line:

```
  (-5)/3                                     5/3
     5/(-3)                               (-5)/(-3)
      =                                       =
    -1.66 --> -1                       1 <-- 1.66
       v       v                       v       v
-  +  -  -  -  +  -  -  -  +  -  -  -  +  -  -  -  +  -
   |           |           |           |           |
  -2          -1           0           1           2
```

the rounding is thus *towards* zero.

b) Yes. Since `a/b` is now defined for all `a` and `b` (except `b == 0`), and `(a/b)*b + a%b == a`, there is only 1 unique solution for `a%b`, so the `%` operator is also well-defiend for all `a` and `b` (except `b == 0`).

Comment: Why is this called 'rounding'? Isn't this truncation?

Comment: @chubsdad: The term "rounding" is much more general than you thought. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer

Answer (score 1):

a) "Truncation towards zero" simply means that any decimal part is lopped off.  The truncated number is always at least as close to 0 as, and usually closer than, the original number.

This is most noticeable in negative numbers, but the goal is to make it less tricky to use `/` and `%` with negative numbers (since currently, any implementation can handle it however they choose).  -7/4  can be thought of two ways: -2 with a remainder of 1, or -1 with a remainder of -3.  And there are compilers and processors that handle it both ways.  Since -7/4 is actually -1.75, "truncation toward zero" would give you -1, so the latter way is what'll be standard.

b)
That's what it looks like.  It's always been semi-defined ("implementation-defined"), but this looks like an attempt to define what should have been standard from the beginning.