# Simple Maths - calculating a rolling window of numbers (aha! negative modulus/remainders!!)

Tags: math

I'm almost embarrased to ask this, because it's probably VERY obvious - but I can't see a way out of this neatly and suspect there is one.

I have a variable which I need to add/subtract values from - but I want to keep it within a range of values, looping around at either end - e.g.

Range is 0-3 so values are 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3 - and this does that

```
x = (x + val) MOD 4
```

When val is negative, however, we should see 0,3,2,1,0,3,2,1 and the solution is FAR less elegant

```
x = (x + val) MOD 4
if (x < 0) x = 4 + x;
```

That works, but it's clunky and I can't help thinking there might be a 'one line' solution to this - but I'm damned if I can think of it? :)

*prepares for embarrassment*

Comment: Why does it have to be one line long?

Comment: The proper modulus operator already does this. If you implement this using the remainder operator (commonly `%` in programming languages) then the behaviour changes with negative numbers and you need the two-liner that you posted. In other words: you probably used the remainder operator instead of the proper modulus operator.

Comment: @raedwald it could be 50 lines if it were elegant and look and feel like a bodge :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284644/why-is-operator-referred-to-as-the-modulus-operator-instead-of-the-remainder

Comment: @TaZ aha - now I realise this isn't an uncommon question and that how languages approach Modulus varies wildly (and the suggestion appears to be that neither approach is 'right' - you just have to work around it...)!?

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis - and many other questions now I realise that Modulus doesn't have a fixed behaviour with negative results...

Comment: So, not a silly question after all :)

Comment: This question actually has a devastatingly simple answer which I'm frantically checking works -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412179/best-way-to-make-javas-modulus-behave-like-it-should-with-negative-numbers - and it seems to...!

Comment: Difficult to choose an answer to this - TaZ determined the problem, Rody outlined one solution and the question I linked contains a specific solution which works in Javascript (which is what I'm using tho I didn't mention that!) - hmmmmm....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by TaZ, most "modulo" operators are really remainder operators that only work like a "mathematical modulo" for `x+val >= 0`.

In c++, as found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/19502/) (with some modifications), you can define a more "mathematically correct" modulo like so

```
double mod(double x, double y) { return y!=0 ? x-floor(x/y)*y : x; }
```

(perhaps also make an integer version), such that

```
x = mod(x+val,4);
```

works for both positive and negative `x+val`.

Comment: My particular need is with Javascript - and the question I quoted in comments earlier suggests...

((a+b)%a+b)%b

which is really elegant but I'm scribbling on notepads to check it :)